# Nested relationships within Join Tables - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nested, polymorphic-associations

I'm rather new to Rails and have a question about how to successfully add sub-categories to an existing Join Table relationship.

For example, assume I'm building a job board. Each job has 5 major filter categories ( `Job_Type [General Management, Finance & Operations, etc.]`, `Industry [ Technology, Healthcare, etc.]`, `Region [Northwest, Southeast, etc.]`, and so on ). I want each of those to have subcategories as well ( ex. This job post has a `Region > Southeast > South Carolina > Greenville` ).

Setting up an initial Join Table association for the 5 major filter types made sense for future filtering and searchability.

**EDIT**

Here is my current `Posting` Model

```
class Posting < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader

  belongs_to :recruiter, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :company
  has_many :interests
  has_many :comments, as: :commentable
  has_and_belongs_to_many :job_types
  has_and_belongs_to_many :industries
  has_and_belongs_to_many :regions
  has_and_belongs_to_many :market_caps
  has_and_belongs_to_many :ownerships
  has_many :users, through: :interests
  acts_as_followable
end
```

I'm currently using join tables instead of an array directly on the ActiveRecord for speed sake and for filtering/searching capabilities later on. It also allows me to use these join table in conjunction with a plethora of other necessary ActiveRecord associations.

Here is a snippet of what `job_type` looks like:

```
class JobType < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :postings
  has_and_belongs_to_many :news_items
  has_and_belongs_to_many :companies
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
  has_and_belongs_to_many :mkt_ints
end
```

This allows me access to a simple array of associated models, but I'm confused as to how to move past that to an array of arrays with potential further nested arrays. It feels clunky to add additional join tables for the first join tables. I'm sure there's a better solution and would love to get any insight you might have.

**SECOND EDIT**

Here's a representational picture of what I am trying to do if it helps.

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Just a friendly tip, you'd probably get more help if you tried creating those model relationships yourself and then posted the code for commentary and assistance.

Comment: Thanks @ValAsensio. I appreciate the feedback, and I understand that. I'm continuing to do some research on it and will post code once I have something I believe is worth posting. I don't want to waste any more of others time than is necessary. =]

Comment: I thought someone would jump in. "Join Table association for the 5 major filter types" this is non-standard Rails language, and not relatable to database SQL either, so maybe that's keeping answerers at bay. I hope someone chimes in to help, but it may not happen; thus is life on Stack Overflow. I have a few non-answered questions myself. Everyone does, so don't lose heart over it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**

---

The data for this table will, most likely, not be changing which eases the complexity and presented a more straightforward solution.

I created separate roles within a single table to limit queries and join tables. The resulting `Region` ActiveRecord looks like this:

```
class CreateRegions < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :regions do |t|
      t.string :role # role [ region, state, city ]
      t.integer :parent # equal to an integer [ state.id = city.parent ] or null [ region has no parent ]
      t.string :name # [ ex: Southeast, South Carolina, Charleston ]
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end

end
```

This gives me all of the fields necessary to create relationships in a single table and easily sort it into nested checkboxes using the `parent.id`.

Thank you to everyone who viewed this question and to [Val Asensio](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4200307/val-asensio) for your helpful comment and encouragement.